# How to use PHP and MySQL to style a website dynamically?

Tags: php, css, mysql, sass

I am looking for a way to use a database table to style parts of a website. I want this because I have multiple websites and I want an easy way to style default parts easily.

Example:

I have a `tbl_settings` and it contains the columns "Setting_Id, Site_Id, Label, Key, Value". 
Key can be "footer_bg" and the value will be "ff3300" for example.

How can I use php to send the value to css/sass?
Maybe create a url that doesnt really exists and echo css into it? Just like with ajax.

Any ideas, I really have no idea...?

Comment: Maybe make a rewrite rule that has `style.css` load `style.php` and then have the PHP build your CSS sheet as needed.

Comment: To build on @user3783243 's comment. I don't know that writing a css file with PHP is the most scalable answer. But, you could use those setting values to point to a different css file depending on the site you're using.

Comment: You can do this if you're careful with caching considerations.

Comment: actually i did something like that before. i will check and write what I did for that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i do not think this design is going to work well. Whatever way you are going to code this, you will end up with massive query load on the database. Imagine firing up queries for every class you put into your html, for every user of your app.

I will go for a more "gentle" way of dynamic styling, create some "template" css, store their path into the db and load them into your page dynamically.

Comment: actually he can do that operation in 1 or 2 queries with his table structer.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you can link a php file as css.but there is some problems with updating values and between stored values but you can workaround this.
you can link a php file as css like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dynamic.php" media="screen">
```

Than you need to set this file's header.

`css/dynamic.php`:

```
<?php
/** set header **/
header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
```

After that you can pretty much can `echo` any css rule you want. And you can do your queries in that file.

But this cant solve browser history problem as long as the file name is same if there is a copy in browser history it will be the one used for the site. for fix that you can give your rule sets some unique random identifier. when you change any rule below that identifier you can update that identifier with a new one. how you handel that is in your hands. no metter how you set that you can use this identifier in you html link and pass that as a parameter.

```
<!-- I assume that identifier stored in '$id' -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dynamic.php?somekey=<?=$id?>" media="screen">
```

than you can access this updated value in your file

```
<?php
/** set header **/
header("Content-type: text/css");
/*Dont forget to escape this before passing it in to sql*/
$id = $_GET["somekey"];
?>
```

if you handel id's of value sets of your `css` you can handel browser hisory as well.

I be happy to corrected if I am wrong.